# Application's launch was blocked by another program

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YukqR.png) Alright so I have a program that I have been using for a few years that is made using excel that is compiled with xcell compiler that now gives me this error every time I try to run it. I must note that the default file location is a shared network drive (not sure if that could cause some kind of issue) and that this program has always been ran in Excel 2010 (which is currently installed)

Yesterday I was having issues with my Outlook 2016 so I went to run the "Online repair" option while I went to lunch. When I came back I had noticed that all of my office stuff had just vanished with no prompts on the screen for anything. I then looked at all programs and saw that "Office 365" was still there so I attempted to run the repair tool again to which I got an error message and had to use Microsoft removal tool (which removed all of my office versions).

Today I have installed Office 2010 again as well as recently installed Office 2016 (CTR) but however as stated about when I try to open the program I am greeted with this big fat error and I have no idea what could actually be causing it as nothing else has changed. Is there any logs I could check that might have more information other than "another program". I have checked my AV and even turned it off just to see and nothing.

Comment: It would help if you would reproduce in the question the exact error(s) that you are seeing.

Comment: The title is exactly what the error is telling me, "Applicantion's launch was blocked by another program."

Comment: This is not a normal Windows error message. Please take a screen shot and add it to your question.

Comment: Alright, I've added a link for it at the start (since I am unable to emblem yet).      Also, I've tried other stuff from the network and all of that opens just fine.

Comment: This may be an error generated by the compiled-excel program; you should contact the developer for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ on the xcell product has this to say about how it works:

> "[The original xls file is modified by removing all formulas] This file is a data provider between compiled EXE and Excel. It is
>   used to format calculated values and to reflect them into Excel."

The EXE rips all the guts out of the excel workbook and uses it for formatting only, and operates by automation.

So the first thing you should check is whether the Excel versions is 32-bit or 64-bit, and compare that to what the xcell program wants. Not all Automation/ODBC api/library/magic is bundled nor supported by both 64 and 32-bit Excel.

[Source](http://doneex.com/technical-questions-and-answers/)